# FFTW of double samples saved in file

Tags: c, fft, fftw, libsndfile

I am trying to calculate FFT on 53k double samples using FFTW library and on it's basis guess what's the fundamental frequency of the signal. Samples are generated by sndfile library on the basis of wav input file (program loads in wav file, generates samples of double data and saves them to a text file). Each sample's order of magnitude is ranging from -0.0009 to +0.0009. After calculating FFT using function presented below, I receive in[0][0] = -2.142. Either this is an incorrect method of retrieving data or the input file is incorrect. What am I doing wrong? Is it the wrong data passing to FFTW function, is the data stored in file incorrect or the function I have written is incorrect? Buffer is a float array containing samples.

```
static fftw_complex* calculateFourier(float* buffer, const unsigned int bufferLen)
{

    unsigned int i;
    //const unsigned short windowSize = 1024;
    fftw_plan result;
    fftw_complex *out, *in;

    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * bufferLen);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc( sizeof(fftw_complex) * bufferLen);

    double* doubleBuffer = castToDouble(buffer, bufferLen);

    for(i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++)
    {
        in[i][0] = doubleBuffer[i];
        in[i][1] = 0.000000000000;
    }

    result = fftw_plan_dft_1d(bufferLen, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    //result = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(fileSize, castToDouble(buffer, bufferLen), out, FFTW_MEASURE);

    fftw_execute(result);

    fftw_destroy_plan(result);

    return out;
}
static double* castToDouble(float* buffer, const unsigned int bufferLen)
{
    unsigned int i;
    double* doubleBuffer = (double*)malloc( sizeof(double) * bufferLen); 

    for(i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++)
        doubleBuffer[i] = (double)buffer[i];

    return doubleBuffer;

}
```

Comment: and what does the `castToDouble` do?

Comment: Since sndfile library saves samples as floats and fftw requires double type samples, it simply casts every sample to double.

Comment: the fft of fftw is not normalized. See http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029 : if the buffer is 53000 long, then out[0][0] ("zero frequency") is 53000 times the average of the buffer, that is the sum of all the items of the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't applied a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to your raw data. As a result, the Fourier transform has a strong frequency component that corresponds to the length of your sample buffer.

Try applying a Hanning window by replacing this line:

```
in[i][0] = doubleBuffer[i];
```

with this:

```
in[i][0] = doubleBuffer[i] * 0.5 * (1.0 - cos(2.0 * M_PI * i / (bufferLen - 1)));
```

(Obviously this window function can be cached if you need to use it repeatedly.)

Comment: In such situation each real component in out array (out[i][0]) is equal to 0

Comment: Hanning window is missing `i` factor in `cos` argument, so it should be `0.5 * (1.0 - cos(2.0 * i * M_PI / (bufferLen - 1)))`

Comment: @SleuthEye Thanks for spotting that

Comment: @Kokos34 I missed out a factor in the Hanning window formula. Try it again now.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage It still does not give me the answer I am expecting. Isn't out[0][0] a fundamental frequency of the signal? The answer is -1.87 and after I calculate magnitude as sqrt(re^2 + im^2), it gives the result of 1.87. What else do i have to do to get the result of fundamental frequency of the signal?

Comment: @Kokos34 No, `out[0]` is the DC component You need to find the value of `i` that gives you the largest `out[i]`. This will correspond to a frequency of `i * samplesPerSecond / bufferLen`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Ok, just the summary now:
samplesPerSecond is 44,1kHz, so 44100, bufferLen is about 55k and max i according to function seeking for index of max value of buffer was 639. I calculated fundamental frequency of the signal as 639*44100/55000), which was 522samples/second. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kokos34 Almost. The result is a frequency (in Hz), and I get a value of 512.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Where did that value come from? What input values did you use? The methodology is correct, right?

Comment: I used your input values: 639*44100/55000=512.36. With complex waveforms, this method will sometimes discover harmonics of the fundamental frequency instead of the fundamental frequency itself. To find the fundamental frequency more reliably, you should probably use a technique such as [autocorrelation or harmonic product spectrum analysis](http://cnx.org/contents/i5AAkZCP@2/Pitch-Detection-Algorithms)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage This is exactly my task! I have to:
1. Check fundamental frequency using FFT
2. Check my result using autocorrelation function. 
May I ask you few questions concerning autocorrelation in private messages? I also implemented it however few things also fail and I have no wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good long look at what is wrong with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prn (float *a, int n);

int main (void)
{
    float floatarray[] = { 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0 };

    prn (floatarray, sizeof floatarray/sizeof *floatarray);

    return 0;
}

void prn (float *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    double *d = (double *)a;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" a[%d] : %01.0lf\n", i, d[i]);
}
```

Run it, what happens? Why?

What is the `sizeof` a `float`? What is the `sizeof` a `double`? What happens when the cast `double *d = (double *)a;` takes place? How many bytes are expected in each element of `d`? How many are there? Your

```
double* doubleBuffer = castToDouble(buffer, bufferLen);
```

causes the exact same problem.

**Element-by-Element Cast/Assignment Required**

Whether you use a new `double` array allocated with `malloc` (or `calloc`), you must do an *element-by-element* cast/assignment to complete the cast of the array. Here is the same code with a few additions using a variable length array to avoid allocating memory dynamically:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void castfloatdouble (double *d, float *f, int n);
void prn (float *a, int n);
void prndouble (double *d, int n);

int main (void)
{
    float floatarray[] = { 0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0 };
    int n = (int)(sizeof floatarray/sizeof *floatarray);
    double doublearray[n];  /* memset is a good idea to zero a VLA */

    prn (floatarray, n);  /* incorrect results due to typesize mismatch */
    putchar ('\n');

    castfloatdouble (doublearray, floatarray, n);

    prndouble (doublearray, n);  /* correct results after deep cast/assign */
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

void castfloatdouble (double *d, float *f, int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        d[i] = (double)f[i];
}

void prn (float *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    double *d = (double *)a;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" a[%d] : %01.0lf\n", i, d[i]);
}

void prndouble (double *d, int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" a[%d] : %01.0lf\n", i, d[i]);
}
```

**Output Showing Incorrect & Correct Results**

```
$ ./bin/castfloatdouble2
 a[0] : 2048
 a[1] : 16777220
 a[2] : 805306499
 a[3] : 0
 a[4] : 0
 a[5] : 0

 a[0] : 0
 a[1] : 5
 a[2] : 10
 a[3] : 15
 a[4] : 20
 a[5] : 25
```

Comment: But my castToDouble allocates memory for proper size, i guess:
double* doubleBuffer = (double*)malloc( sizeof(double) * bufferLen);

Comment: It's hard to *guess* at what it is doing without seeing the code, but even if you allocate memory, if you are not then doing an element-by-element cast and assignment of each `buffer[i]` value into new `double` storage then the same problem will exist. You must take care in how you convert an array of 4-byte floats into an array of 8-byte doubles. Remember `array` implies *sequentially stored in memory*.

Comment: I edited the post to contain the castToDouble function implementation . Is it correct? Woudl you like me to post some additional code?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'll drop another way of using a static array as an edit to my answer.